# Guice won't intercept annotated methods

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a situation where Guice is working for some bindings, and not at all for others. Clearly I am using the API incorrectly.

In part, it's probably because I'm trying to get too "fancy" with how I'm using Guice. I've created an inheritance tree of `Module`s and I think I've gotten too clever (or foolish!) for my own good.

Before you look at the code below, just please understand my *intention*, which was to provide a reusable `Module` that I can place in a JAR and share across multiple projects. This abstract, reusable `Module` would provide so-called "default bindings" that any implementing `Module` would automatically honor. Things like an AOP `MethodInterceptor` called `Profiler`, which looks for methods annotated with `@Calibrated` and automatically logs how long it took for that method to execute, etc.

Observe the following:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@RetentionPolicy(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface Calibrated{}

public class Profiler implement MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation arg0) throws Throwable {
        // Eventually it will calculate and log the amount of time
        // it takes an intercepted method to execute, hence "Profiler".
        System.out.println("Intercepted!");
        return arg0.proceed();
    }
}

public abstract class BaseModule implements Module {
    private Binder binder;

    public BaseModule() {
        super();
    }

    public abstract void bindDependencies();

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder bind) {
        // Save the binder Guice passes so our subclasses can reuse it.
        setBinder(bind);

        // TODO: For now do nothing, down the road add some
        // "default bindings" here.

        // Now let subclasses define their own bindings.
        bindDependencies();
    }

    // getter and setter for "binder" field
    // ...
}

public abstract class AbstractAppModule extends BaseModule {
    /* Guice Injector. */
    private Injector injector;

    // Some other fields (unimportant for this code snippet)

    public AbstractAppModule() {
        super();
    }

    // getters and setters for all fields
    // ...

    public Object inject(Class<?> classKey) {
        if(injector == null)
            injector = Guice.createInjector(this);

        return injector.getInstance(classKey);
    }
}
```

So, to use this small library:

```
public class DummyObj {
    private int nonsenseInteger = -1;

    // getter & setter for nonsenseInteger

    @Calibrated
   public void shouldBeIntercepted() {
       System.out.println("I have been intercepted.");
   }
}

public class MyAppModule extends AbstractAppModule {
    private Profiler profiler;

    // getter and setter for profiler

    @Override
    public void bindDependencies() {
        DummyObj dummy = new DummyObj();
        dummy.setNonsenseInteger(29);

        // When asked for a DummyObj.class, return this instance.
        getBinder().bind(DummyObj.class).toInstance(dummy);

        // When a method is @Calibrated, intercept it with the given profiler.
        getBinder().bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(),
            Matchers.annotatedWith(Calibrated.class),
            profiler);
    }
}

public class TestGuice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Profiler profiler = new Profiler();
        MyAppModule mod = new MyAppModule();
        mod.setProfiler(profiler);

        // Should return the bounded instance.
        DummyObj dummy = (DummyObj.class)mod.inject(DummyObj.class);

        // Should be intercepted...
        dummy.shouldBeIntercepted();

        System.out.println(dummy.getNonsenseInteger());
    }
}
```

This is a lot of code so I may have introduced a few typos when keying it all in, but I assure you this code compiles and throws no exceptions when ran.

Here's what happens:

- The `@Calibrated shouldBeIntercepted()` method is *not* intercepted; but...
- The console output shows the dummy's nonsense integer as...29!!!!

So, regardless of how poor a design you may *think* this is, you can't argue that Guice is indeed working for 1 binding (the instance binding), but not the AOP method interception.

If the instance binding wasn't working, then I would happily revisit my design. But something else is going on here. I'm wondering if my inheritance tree is throwing the `Binder` off somehow?

And I've verified that I am binding the interceptor to the annotation correctly: I created another package where I just implement `Module` (instead of this inheritance tree) and use the same annotation, the same `Profiler`, and it works perfectly fine.

I've used `Injector.getAllBindings()` to print out the map of all my `MyAppModule`'s bindings as Strings. Nothing is cropping up as the clear source of this bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interception only works on Objects created by Guice (see "Limitations" http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP#Limitations).  You are using "new" to create the DummyObj, so no matter how clever your Module is Set up, the instance  is created Outside guice.

Here's a little snipplet based on your coding. (I use your Calibrated Annotation, but had everything else in one class. You should have a look at "AbstractModule". It saves a lot of manual stuff you did with your Module-Hierarchy.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule implements MethodInterceptor {

@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {

    System.out.println("Intercepted@invoke!");

    return methodInvocation.proceed();
}

@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(Integer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("nonsense")).toInstance(29);
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Calibrated.class), this);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Dummy dummy = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule()).getInstance(Dummy.class);

    dummy.doSomething();

    System.out.println(dummy.getNonsense());
}
}
```

And my Dummy:

```
public class Dummy {

@Inject
@Named("nonsense")
private int nonsense;


public int getNonsense() {
    return nonsense;
}


public void setNonsense(int nonsense) {
    this.nonsense = nonsense;
}

@Calibrated
public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("I have been intercepted!");
}
}
```

So you see? I never use the word "new" (except for the Module ....). I let Guice handle the Dummy-Object and just configure the value for the nonsense int, which is then injected.

Output:

```
Intercepted@invoke!
I have been intercepted!
29
```

Comment: so is what you're saying that: (1) since I am using `new`, I'm not actually obtaining the `Dummy` through Guice; and (2) since I'm then running a `Calibrated` method from the non-Guice-injected `Dummy`, that Guice is failing to intercept it? Is that the gist? If so, that makes perfect sense. If not, can you please clarify? Thanks again for all your help and such a great answer (+1) !

Comment: your DummyObj-instance is not created by guice. Its created by you and than bound in the module, so you will always get the same pre-created instance. 
So basically: yes, I am saying (1) and (2). Its a bit tricky to understand, read the wohle guice-aop site (link above). And dont ask me why this has to be that way ... Its a good best practice imo to avoid "new" wherever possible.